# The code saves to database not this thing (select option)

Tags: javascript, php, database, function, input

HTML code:

```
<select name="category" onchange="change(this.selectedIndex)">
<option selected disabled hidden>Choose your category</option>
<option value="1">TVs</option>
<option value="2">Laptops</option>
<option value="3">Smartphones</option>
<option value="4">Peripherals</option>
<option value="5">Components</option>
<option value="6">Cameras</option>    
</select>
```

PHP code:

```
$category = $_POST['category'];
$db->INSERT("INSERT INTO items Values(NULL,'$name','$category','$brand','$nick','$review','$rating')");
```

I want to save to base by POST my category. For example TVs. And the program saves "value" for example "1". When the value didn't exist it worked, but now I need it to JS function. How to do - name="category" reads option, not value?

Comment: you're open to SQL injection and should address imminently

Comment: what should I add?

Answer (score -1):

So basically what a value is for is to indicate what an input should hold as a content,
so consider doing this

```
<select name="category" onchange="change(this.selectedIndex)">
 <option selected disabled hidden>Choose your category</option>
 <option value="TVs">TVs</option>
 <option value="Laptops">Laptops</option>
 <option value="Smartphones">Smartphones</option>
 <option value="Peripherals">Peripherals</option>
 <option value="Components">Components</option>
 <option value="Cameras">Cameras</option>    
</select>
```

hope it helped!!

Comment: It doesn't work. I think selectedIndex must be integer, so value must be integer

Comment: OK now works. I changed also this.selectedIntex to this.value, thanks for indicate possibly solution